# Multiple (n times) repeating route parameters

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-router, url-parameters

How do you define a route with route parameters, if you want to allow the same parameter to repeat *n* times.

E.g.

```
  { 
    path: '/route/:id1/:id2/:id3/:id4', // etc.
    component: SomeComponent
  }
```

Is it possible to simplify the way to allow *n* IDs.

Comment: Well it is a string basically so you can always run a loop to create it, but I'm more curious about the use case of such a route.

Comment: You could use something like `[...new Array(4).keys()].map( i => ":id" + (i+1)).join("/")`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava The use case is a comparison of multiple objects in a visualisation. The user may be able to either show the data of a single object or to compare up to a few dozens of objects.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the idea, but then I would need to know the lenght of the array in advance. I am looking for a way to have the number of parameters to be variable.

Comment: Which array are you talking about whose length you'd need to know? In my code just replace the 4 by any number and that's your variable number of parameters. If you've got an input array of variable length use it instead of the `new Array(n)`. Just in case here's a sample : https://ideone.com/TGCuyf

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the segments of `this.route.url`, like in the component code below:

**Route definition:**

```
export const Routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  children: [{
    path: '**',
    component: Component
  }]
}];
```

**Component:**

```
@Component()
export class Component {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.url.subscribe((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
      segments.forEach(segment => {
        console.log(segment); // each segment resembles one parameter like in my question
      })
    });

  }
}
```